# Install LibSVM for Matlab R2014a in Windows 8.1

Tags: matlab, installation, svm, libsvm, mex

I have a problem, I can not install the library LIBSVM (for the SVM training). I look this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz_4h_bH7-c
but when I type "mex -setup" Matlab shows to me an error: "Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/win64. "
Please, help to me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a supported C/C++ for Matlab to run the `make` instruction (the `make` instruction compiles the LibSVM source code).

Download (and install) Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1, close and reopen Matlab and then run `mex -setup` to check that Matlab detects your compiler. Hope it does fix your problem.

Same story on Mac OS X by the way: you have to install XCode for Matlab to detect a supported C/C++ compiler.

Comment: nothing...I have installed SDK 7.1 from http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/win64.
but I have the same error..

Comment: In this page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
I have click DOWNLOAD and installed it..

Comment: It clearly states that there is a previous .NET version installed. Go to the Control Panel, uninstall the .NET version you have and then try again